# Nav Deep Link from a foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'm trying to navigate to a fragment in my navigation graph from a foreground service notification. I used the below code to create an explicit deep link which didn't work out as expected.

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this) // this is the Service context!
            .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.primary_app_nav)
            .setDestination(R.id.shareSheetFragment)
            .setArguments(bundle)
            .createPendingIntent()
```

After reading the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link), I got to know that you need to use the activity context and not any other context (in my case it is service context).

> Note that if the provided context is not an Activity, the constructor
> uses PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage() as the default
> activity to launch, if available.

My question is how do I get hold of the `MainActivity` context from within my foreground service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't figured out a way to do it with explicit deep links, but I settled for a solution which leverages implicit deep link.

First, add a deep link to your fragment in the nav graph XML.

```
<deepLink android:id="@+id/deepLink"
   app:uri="my-app://com.example.app/hotspot?ssid={ssid}&amp;passkey={passkey}" />
```

Add the `<nav-graph />` tag within your `<activity />` in the manifest. This will ensure that all the intent filters are created and merged to your manifest.

```
<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/primary_app_nav" />
```

Create your `PendingIntent` for the notification as follows.

```
fun getNotificationPendingIntent(ssid: String, passkey: String): PendingIntent {
     val uri = Uri.parse("my-app://com.example.app/hotspot?ssid=$ssid&passkey=$passkey")
     val bundle = Bundle().apply { putParcelable(SHARE_DEEP_LINK_KEY, uri) }
     val intent = Intent(this, SailsActivity::class.java).apply {
          putExtras(bundle)
          // to clear the back stack
          addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                     or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
     }
     return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, launchShareSheetCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

Finally, you need to handle the deep link intents from your `Activity` class' `onCreate()` method.

```
private fun handleDeepLinkIntent() {
    val deepLink = intent.extras?.getParcelable(SHARE_DEEP_LINK_KEY) as? Uri
    deepLink?.also {
        val intent = Intent(this, SenderService::class.java)
        this.bindService(intent, serviceConn, Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT)
        navigateDeepLink(it)
    }
}

private fun navigateDeepLink(uri: Uri) {
    findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).apply {
        if (graph.hasDeepLink(uri)) 
            navigate(uri)
        else {
            currentDestination?.getAction(id)?.let {
                navigate(id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Deep link URI arguments are automatically available to you in the destination fragment.

```
if (arguments != null) {
     val ssid = requireArguments().getString("ssid")
     val passkey = requireArguments().getString("passkey")
}
```